# Point in a spherical triangle test

Tags: geometry, polar-coordinates, spherical-geometry

Given three latitude/longitude coordinates on a sphere forming a triangle, how do I test if a point p is inside that triangle?

I know latitude and longitude implies Earth and Earth is not perfectly spherical, but in my simplified model it will be. Essentially I'm interested in a point-in-triangle test for spherical geometry, using polar coordinates.

Comment: Defining a triangle from three points is a little more subtle on a sphere than on a Euclidean plane as there are usually two line segments joining two points as well as having to define inside and outside the triangle.  But assuming you can find the area of a spherical triangle (proportional to the angle excess) from the points, you could check whether the areas of the three triangles involving $p$ add up to the area of the original triangle.

Answer (score 7):

Note that for the point $p$ to lie within the spherical triangle bound by $\{ p_1, p_2, p_3 \}$, the intersection of the ray from the origin to $p$ (basically the line joining $(0,0,0)$ and $p$) with the 3D-plane defined by $\{ p_1, p_2, p_3 \}$ lies inside the planar triangle $\{ p_1, p_2, p_3 \}$. This can be formulated with the unknown quantities $\lambda$, $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$, to be determined by solving the linear system of equations:
$$
\alpha p_1 + \beta p_2 + \gamma p_3 = \lambda p
$$

If $\lambda, \alpha, \beta, \gamma > 0$ and $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 1$, then the projection of $p$ onto the plane $\{p_1, p_2, p_3\}$ lies in the triangle $\{p_1, p_2, p_3\}$ and therefore the point $p$ itself lies in the spherical triangle. With a little jugglery, this can be implemented in any popular linear algebra package very easily. I would start by solving the linear system:
$$
\frac{\alpha}{\lambda} p_1 + \frac{\beta}{\lambda} p_2 + \frac{\gamma}{\lambda} p_3 = p
$$
And then determining $\lambda$ by forcing $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

I like to think about this more geometrically. I'm not sure if it is more efficient or not.
For a triangle, or any convex polygon on the sphere, a point is inside if it is on the correct side of all of the planes that form the polygon. I.e. each edge of the polygon is an arc on a great circle, and that circle lies in a plane.

Here I assume that you know the order of the vertices, and can visit them in a CCW order.

Compute the normal for the plane of each edge with $n_{ij}$ = $v_i \, X \,v_j$. 
Then take the dot product of each normal with the point p. 
$inside_{ij}$ = $p$ dot $n_{ij}$
The inside test fails if any result $inside_{ij}$ is < 0.